# How to return other datatypes while writing Custom class mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Write now i have a situation. I am writing a custom mediator which implements mediate function that returns boolean. But instead i want to return other datatype as well. i am trying to achieve thsi by writing a custom code to add two numbers and return the result. but i am not able to figure out, how i can return integer instead of boolean. Please provide me an example related to this situation. 
I have written the code inside custom class mediator as:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        System.out.println("Checkpoint1: OpenPublication.mediate()");
        if (getChanneluri() != null && !getChanneluri().isEmpty()) {
            messageContext.setProperty("SessionID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            System.out.println("Checkpoint2: SessionID Property set");
            synapseConfig = messageContext.getConfiguration();
            System.out.println("Checkpoint3: messageContextSessionID = " + messageContext.getProperty("SessionID"));
            System.out.println("Checkpoint3: messageID = " + messageContext.getMessageID());
                    }
        return false;
    }
```

Now i want to retreive this property value of "SessionID" in my sequence. How to do this.
    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot make a class mediator return anything other than a boolean value. A class mediator, when extending the `AbstractMediator` class, has to implement the boolean mediate method; as you pointed out.

You may try setting properties to the Synapse message context to pass values between different mediators.

For example:

```
public class myMediator extends AbstractMediator {

    private String property1 = "aProperty";
    private String property2;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {

        messageContext.setProperty("MyProperty", property1);
        property2 = (String) messageContext.getProperty("MyProperty");


        return true;
    }
```

In the above example, the two String variables will end up having the same value "aProperty". In this manner, you can expose any type of object to the Synapse message context and retrieve it elsewhere.

Comment: so suppose i have set a property1 as "someString". can i retreive this property1 when calling the class mediator in my sequence and suppose i want to set property2 from sequence using payload factory then How to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Say that you have added a property 'property1' with a value "someString" in your sequence. Inside a class mediator, you can retrieve that property by using the method messageContext.getProperty("property1"), and assigning it to a String (after typecasting it to String). 
For setting properties in a sequence, you can use the <property> tag. For example, 
<property name="property2" value="anotherString"/> can be used to set a property named 'property2'.

Comment: PayloadFactory is used to transform/replace the entire message context (i. e. the response). See http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16846452 for examples. For your purpose, I think the Property mediator (used above) would be better suited.

Comment: No you didnt get my question. i want to set the value of setter properties of the class mediator using payload factory and i want to get the value from getter methods of class mediator in wso2 esb's property mediator?

Comment: i have set messageContext.setProperty("SessionID", UUID.randomUUID().toString()); like this and now i want to access it in my sequence using log mediator as <sequence key="OpenPublication"/>
      <log level="full">
         <property name="SessionID_After_OpenPublicationSeq" value="get-property('SessionID')"/>
      </log>
How to do this?

Comment: Properties are not tied to a class mediator. They can be used throughout the service, and in some cases across services as well. For more info, see http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Property+Mediator.
To answer your question, you should use the get-property() function as an expression. i. e. 
<log>
      <property name="SessionID_After_OpenPublicationSeq" expression="get-property('SessionID')"/>
</log>

Comment: I have tried what you had suggested me. I used My modified sequence is:<class name="wso2.org.Communicator.OpenPublication">
      <axis2ns4:property xmlns:axis2ns4="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="channeluri" value="testuri"/>
   </class>
   <log level="full">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="SessionID_After_OpenPublicationSeq" expression="get-property('SessionID')"/>
   </log>. But i am not able to get the sessionId that i have set in my class mediator code. Please help me on this.

Comment: In that case, please ensure that the class mediator returns `true` rather than `false`. If you're getting any errors, please post the error.

Comment: Hi Gokul, Thanks for your help. I have a question. How can i pass property value inside class mediator's parameter. I mean to say that class mediator's property requires value but i need to pass expression instead of value?